# Python Pandas - Calculate mean using criteria from two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the mean of a Pandas data frame column using selection criteria from two other columns. In the code below, there are a "Trace" and "Sample" columns that are to be used for selection criteria, while the numbers in the "Value" column are to be used in the calculation. I want to group by the "Trace" number and only take the average of "Sample" numbers 3, 4, and 5. Then, I would like to create a new column in the original dataframe "df" and place the calculated mean values in all of the rows corresponding to the correct "Trace" number.

```
d = {"Trace": [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], "Sample": [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5], "Value": [2,3,5,6,1,8,9,5,4,3]}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: groupby + mean ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this, filter your dataframe first, then groupy with mean, and join back to original dataframe on 'Trace' (which is the common column name between the dataframes are `reset_index` on results of groupby):

```
df[df['Sample'].isin([3,4,5])].groupby('Trace')['Value'].mean()\
                              .rename('Avg Value').reset_index().merge(df)
```

Output:

```
   Trace  Avg Value  Sample  Value
0      1          4       1      2
1      1          4       2      3
2      1          4       3      5
3      1          4       4      6
4      1          4       5      1
5      2          4       1      8
6      2          4       2      9
7      2          4       3      5
8      2          4       4      4
9      2          4       5      3
```

OR

```
df.groupby('Trace')\
  .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Sample'].isin([3,4,5]),'Value'].mean())\
  .rename('Avg Value').reset_index().merge(df)
```

Output:

```
   Trace  Avg Value  Sample  Value
0      1        4.0       1      2
1      1        4.0       2      3
2      1        4.0       3      5
3      1        4.0       4      6
4      1        4.0       5      1
5      2        4.0       1      8
6      2        4.0       2      9
7      2        4.0       3      5
8      2        4.0       4      4
9      2        4.0       5      3
```